# Replace single float values in pandas series with array

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to create a one-hot encoding for target values using the built-in iris dataset with pandas. I have split the data into features and target labels. The target labels are a pandas series (single column). I would like to replace the single values with an array so as to represent the target values as one-hot encoding.

I cannot seem to find a way to do this?

Please help!
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMRuW.png)

I tried to use the .replace method to replace the floats with arrays

Comment: Why do you want to change the label (target) to a list?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please share a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code you are having problems with as text, not as an image.

Comment: Welcome. Please reserve tag [pandas3x] for versioning issues. The relevant tag here is [Python]

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has the get_dummies() function for doing this

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
data = load_iris()
target = pd.Series(data.target)
pd.get_dummies(target)


    0       1       2
0   True    False   False
1   True    False   False
2   True    False   False
...
```